# Compiling Lyx 2.2 on Debian

Tags: compiling, qt, lyx

I'm trying to compile [Lyx 2.2](https://www.lyx.org/) on my Debian machine from sources. As usual I run `./autogen.sh && ./configure && make`, but configuration stops here

```
configure: error: cannot compile a simple Qt executable. Check you have the right $QTDIR.
```

So I've installed the `qt5-default` package, but it didn't solve the problem.

The $QTDIR vairable was empty, so I manually set it to `/usr/bin/qmake`, and `/usr/bin`, but none has worked, same error.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QTDIR` shouldn't really be necessary, but try setting it to `/usr/share/qt5`.

You could build the Debian source package instead:

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts dpkg-dev build-essential
sudo apt-get build-dep lyx
dget http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/lyx/lyx_2.2.0-2.dsc
cd lyx-2.2.0
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

The first two commands install the packages necessary to build `lyx`; then `dget` downloads and extracts the source package, and `dpkg-buildpackage` builds it and produces a series of `.deb` packages you can install manually using `dpkg` as usual.

Comment: `sudo apt-get build-dep lyx` This actually worked!

Comment: On 21.04 for me, `sudo apt-get build-dep lyx` would remove python and mendeley (?). I found another solution in the mail archives (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

```
./configure QTDIR=/usr/share/qt5 && make
```

instead of

```
./configure && make
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Per [this answer from the LyX mail archive](https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg106800.html) installing

`libqt5x11extras5-dev libqt5svg5-dev libice-dev qtbase5-dev`

resolved the issue for me on Ubuntu 21.04.